# MicroStrategy - How do I make the month labels of the timeline visualization fixed?

Tags: dashboard, microstrategy

I am making use of the Timeline visualization and below is the sample of my work.

[image: Sample Timeline]

My problem is that, the labels below the timeline are switching to 'per day' when I select an element with a short time range as you can see below:

[image: Filtered Timeline]

Is there any way to keep the said labels from switching from monthly to daily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that everything that I was looking for is in here --> https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline

I hope that anyone who will have the same problems as me when using the timeline will be helped by this.

Thanks.

- Ron